# How to go up one sub-domain in a relative URL?

Tags: url, uri

From a page at `cupcakes.dessert.mysite.com/`, how can I use a relative URL to access images or a style-sheet from `dessert.mysite.com/`?  Is there a way to specify "back one sub-domain" in URIs?

I don't want to use an absolute URL such as `src="http://dessert.mysite.com/images/bg.gif"` because that approach would require a different absolute URL for `salad.mysite.com`, as well as possibly overriding an HTTPS connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible.

To address your second concern, use a protocol-relative URL:

```
src="//dessert.mysite.com/images/bg.gif"
```